# Selectorator.js - selector of all hidden elements on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm implementing heatmap to display all users click on my page using heatmaps.js by Patrick Wied. Heatmap is loaded from collection of "datapoints" for each element. But it takes too long to load....
Issue desc.:

Each datapoint has X,Y coordinates and **selector (retrieved using selectorator.js)** of HTML element on page.
Currently i am getting about 5k points for each page and **I need to check if some elements are not hidden so we won't show heatmap for hidden elements.**

Currently I am using:

```
element = $(data.points[i].Element);
element.is(":hidden"))
```

but this takes about 7 seconds to check all those points which is quite long. 
I have run out of ideas how to avoid/optimize this issue.

Datapoint detail:

> Element: #pageData > tbody > tr:eq(3) > td:eq(4) > a:eq(0)
>     Y:0.6546159
>     X:0.4444231

Pseudo script flow desc.:

```
FOREACH(point in allDatapoints)
{
 ...
   calculation of some parameters needed to show on heamapat
 ...
  if (point.element.is(":hidden"))
  {
    continue;
  }
  pointsToDisplay.push(point)
}
```

I've also tried to get selectors of all hidden elements but `GetSelector()` in selectorator.js and then just go through that array but it takes almost same time as `is(:hidden)` function.

I hope this makes sense.

[image]

[image]

**Fact: Getting selector of an element might take a little time, but reverse process(getting and element based on selector) takes almost no time.**
-> so I can not simply send array of selectors of hidden elements and filter those which would be a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks for edit. @TotaloDotoNeto.

Comment: run a profiler on it and post results? maybe that will give some insight as to what is taking so long

Comment: thanks for the profile, it is as I though, the selectors are killing your page, you will need to think of another way of doing this, possibly via saving the element state when collecting the data

Comment: As I answered below:  [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264020/javascript-selectorator-js-selector-of-all-hidden-elements-on-page?noredirect=1#comment56276950_34267133)

Answer (score 1):

looking at the source of `selectorator` seems to indicate it generates selectors by using an index; i.e. `pageData > tbody > tr:eq(3) > td:eq(4) > a:eq(0)`

Now, retrieving the element via that selector looks quite complicated (i assume that something will need to parse it, and execute the selector to retrieve the actual element;

I'm guessing here that that is what is taking so long, as I said in the comments, a profile will really help.

So, without trying to fix this exact problem, can you rather save the `display` property of the element? this will eliminate the need for checking via jQuery.

**Example for manually checking**

```
element = $(element);
while (element.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'body') {
    if (element.style.display === 'none') {
        return false;
    }

    element = element.parentNode;
    if (!element) break;
}
```

Comment: Saving `display` property wont do much, since some elements may be visible when data are collected but not when heatmap is displayed. That's why I need to go through each point(click) exclusively. 
Parsing selector does not take that much time at all its the `is.("hidden")` function.
Lets say we got 2k points to check. And every time .is(":hidden")) condition is being checked it goes through all elements on page and that could be around 100. Which means 2000*100 conditions evaluation.

Comment: how about not using `is("hidden")` there, try running up the DOM manually to see if the element is actually hidden, ill post an edit quickly

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try that, but is.("hidden") does not only check the display property. But also evaluates other possibilites of element to not be visible. Like zero width and height.. etc.
https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Comment: i know, only used as an examlpe, you can manually check those as well, would like to know if it made a difference :)

Comment: not sure why but i'm getting an error: Unable to get property 'toLowerCase' of undefined or null reference
[here](https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/12/14/tagName.md.png)

Comment: sorry, that is a prototypejs extension, you can just write a method to return  the tagName in lowercase